# Uninstalling xCode on 10.5.2

Tags: xcode, uninstallation

just a short one:

This morning i tried to uninstall my xCode 3 since I needed to free some
disk space. Anyways,  I found that the documented uninstaller:

/Developer/Tools/uninstall-devtools.pl

simply does not exist.
spotlight and locate could'nt find it either.

Is it sufficient just to drag the folder to the waste bin?

thanks in advance

```
               kb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just about disk space, yes. Most of the weight of the developer tools is in /Developer. But there are lots of other places where things get installed (e.g. /usr/lib/*_debug.dylib, /usr/bin/, ...).

Comment: Thy for the answer, but is'nt there any deinstall skript?

  Gruß,

        kb